# Firebase Firestore integrate chat using existing backend for user data

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I develop an iOS application and I'm using Node & Postgres for handling user data and authentication. I would like to add a chat feature to my app and I chose Firestore for this.

**My question is** how should I link the existing user data with a Firebase collection of users without re-implementing the authentication part from the ground up. Right now the authentication is based on JWTs with access and refresh tokens.

In order to link my existing users, I can add the `userId` already present in my database to the `users` collection that I will create in Firestore, but I need some kind of authentication to ensure security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the token for Firebase is also a JWT, it will probably have to be separate from your existing JWT, as it contains Firebase-specific information (such as the project ID), and they're signed with different keys.

After you authenticate the user with your own backend, [mint a custom token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) for Firebase authentication with the information you want to use in Firebase/Firestore and security rules, pass that to the client, and [sign them in](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#sign_in_using_custom_tokens_on_clients) to Firebase with it.